# Python many-to-many dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, many-to-many

I need:

```
{'a': [1, 0],
 'q': [1, 2],
 's': [3, 0],
 'w': [3, 2],
 'x': [3, -2],
 'z': [1, -2]}
```

I have:

```
test0=[1,3]
test1=[2,0,-2]    
test2=[('q', 'a', 'z'),('w', 's', 'x')]
```

Each letter in test2 is assigned a first number that represents the position of its triple within all the triples (from test0) and a second number that represents its position within the triple (from test1).

So, for example, ('q', 'a', 'z') is the first triple and so its first dictionary value will be 1.  The second dictionary value will be 2,0,-2 to get:

```
'q':[1,2],
'a':[1,0],
'z':[1,-2]
```

Similarly, ('w', 's', 'x') is the second triple, so its first dictionary value will be 3.   The second dictionary value will be 2,0,-2 to get:

```
'w':[3,2],
's':[3,0],
'x':[3,-2]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: what's the input exactly?

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Did the answer work for you? Any questions?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to simplify the code to create test3 perhaps using zip, OrderedDict, and/or with a one-liner, something akin to list comprehension but for dictionaries

If you just want a dictionary comprehension oneliner to do the job of your nested for loops, the answer is

```
{test2[k][j]:[2*k+1,test1[j]] for k in range(len(test2)) for j in range(len(test2[k]))}
```

Demo:

```
>>> test1=[2,0,-2]    
>>> test2=[('q', 'a', 'z'),('w', 's', 'x')]
>>> {test2[k][j]:[2*k+1,test1[j]] for k in range(len(test2)) for j in range(len(test2[k]))}
{'a': [1, 0], 'q': [1, 2], 's': [3, 0], 'w': [3, 2], 'x': [3, -2], 'z': [1, -2]}
```

Personally, I think this is a little hard to read. I would stick with the loops and add some comments whats going on (and why) if I were you.